# Indicator variables

Tags: probability

Suppose $n$ couples are randomly seated around a round table. Let $S$ be a random variable representing the number of couples where the two members are seated side by side. We are interested in $E(S)$ the expected number of couples that are seated side by side. Define $2n$ indicator variables, $X_i$, $i=1,2,3,\cdots ,2n$ such that.

$$\begin{cases}X_i=1 & \text{if person $i$ is seated beside their partner for $i=1,2,3,\cdots ,2n$}. \\
X_i=0 &\text{otherwise}\end{cases}$$

Find $P(X_i=1)$   Then use method of indicator variables to find $E(S)$.

I think that to find $P(X_i=1)$ I would say that, I will be sitting next to $2$ of the $2n-1$ people thus $P(X_i)=\frac{2}{2n-1}$.

Then to find $E(S)$ I would say that

\begin{align}E(S)&=\sum E(X_i)\\
&=n \frac{2}{2n-1}\\
&=\frac{2n}{2n-1}\end{align}

Am I on the correct track or am I completely off the mark??

Comment: Well, there are $2n$ of the $X_i$ so you should multiply your sum by $2$....on the other hand, you want the number of couples not the number of individuals, so you should divide by $2$.  Hence the two omitted factors cancel.  Otherwise, looks good.

Comment: I am not sure that it is correct as the $X_i$ variables are dependent. For instance, when n=2, $P(X_2=1 / X_1=1)=1$ while $P(X_2=1 / X_1=0)=0$

Comment: @ArnaudMégret Linearity of Expectation holds whether or not the variables are independent.

Comment: @GrahamKemp Correct ! Elegant method to solve the problem